# Academic career start: Postdoctoral or AP

Tags: career-path, postdocs, early-career, assistant-professor

I am a fresh PhD and I have job offer of Postdoctoral researcher in world  leading university (QS rank 6) and assistant professorship in an average university (QS rank 339). 
What is good for long term academic career?

Comment: Can defer the AP position for year in order to finish hat post-doc? I would not be surprised if the search committee agreed to that! or maybe I would (just a lil bit).

Comment: Tangential comment: Many people use the abbreviation AP for "associate professor" and aP for "assistant professor".

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably about the "long term carreer" it depends on the laws of the country you are working in. Moreover it is related to the type of studies in which you are involved in the "world leading university" compared to the "average university".

In my humble opinion you should decide first of all with the feeling that you have with your future working group. In fact the rank of the university is just an index but you should love the research you are involved and give everything to be one of the best in your field.

Comment: the postdoc PI is one of the leading researcher in my research area and his group is very active in those topics i am interested. On the other hand as AP I can initiate my own research project. But I want to know from senior academic person what is better for my long term career boost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newly graduated Ph.D. and personally, I'd prefer a postdoc position.

I think, that would be completely because I'd aim for getting more experience on the research topic I'm interested in and also couple other things, such as writing grants, proposals, or other important stuff that would lead to learning the basics of taking care of the whole lab.

It might be harder to get a grant the moment you accept the other position. On the other hand, it would give you the chance to work on your own projects.